# How do you change an image on one view controller from another view controller in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift5

I'm currently working on a project for an end of the year assignment and I need help to change a UIImage in my first view controller when the user clicks an item in a list view on the second view controller. I'm using a normal show segue to get to the menu when a button is clicked and this to get back:

Code on second view that goes back to the first view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss (animated: true, completion: nil)
    building = true
    print("\(squareType)")
    print("BUILDING = \(building)")
}
```

How do I get this to activate code on my first view to change images. I already have perimeters that run through both views to tell if it's been clicked and what to make based off of it, but I can't update my images

This is the code I want the other view to activate:

code on my first view that I want to trigger after the second view is dismissed

```
func farmCreator() {
    for i in 0...24 {
        if allCells[i].material == "Forest" && squareType == "Cabin" {
            imageBottom[i].image = UIImage(named:"Farms/2")
        }
        if allCells[i].material == "Forest" && squareType == "Forest Mine" {
            imageBottom[i].image = UIImage(named:"Farms/1") //Change
        }
        
        if allCells[i].material == "Rock" && squareType == "Mine" {
            imageBottom[i].image = UIImage(named:"Farms/1")
        }
        
        if allCells[i].material == "Water" && squareType == "Fishmonger" {
            imageBottom[i].image = UIImage(named:"Farms/3")
        }
        if allCells[i].material == "Water" && squareType == "Water Mine" {
            imageBottom[i].image = UIImage(named:"Farms/1") //Change
        }
        
        if allCells[i].material == "Plains" && squareType == "Farm"{
            imageBottom[i].image = UIImage(named:"Farms/4")
        }
        if allCells[i].material == "Plains" && squareType == "Plain Mine"{
            imageBottom[i].image = UIImage(named:"Farms/1") //Change
        }
        
    }
}
```

Ignore how poorly optimized it is, I'm new

I've tried messing with all of the overrides. These things:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VIEW DID DIS V1")
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VIEW WILL DIS V1")
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VIEW DID APP V1")
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print("VIEW WILL APP V1")
}
```

But they only work on the view that is disappearing with my dismiss and not the view that it moves to. Would I have to use an unwind? How would I implement that??

Comment: Read about the delegation pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegation here. I can't see all your code so I'll have to come up with different names for some things.

Step 1: Create a protocol on top of your ViewController 2 class

```
protocol ViewController2Protocol {
    func didTapRow(squareType: String, material: String)
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    ...
    // Contents of ViewController 2
}
```

Step 2: Create a weak var delegate that's the type of Protocol declared above

```
protocol ViewController2Protocol {
    func didTapRow(squareType: String, material: String)
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ViewController2Protocol? // 2. Add this
    ...
    // Contents of ViewController 2
}
```

Step 3: Call your delegate method and pass the required parameters in didSelectRow before dismissing

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Assuming you have: var material: String, and var building: String
    delegate?.didTapRow(material: material, building: building) // 3. Not sure what parameters you need to send to ViewController1. Just guessing.
    dismiss (animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Step 4: Conform to, and implement the protocol in ViewController 1

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController, ViewController2Protocol { // Conform to protocol
    func didTapRow(squareType: String, material: String) { // Implement it
        // Call the method you want to get triggered by tapping here
        farmCreator(squareType: squareType, building: building) // Change this method to accept the parameters as needed
    }
}
```

Step 5. Make sure you set ViewController1 as the delegate wherever you're transitioning to ViewController2 in your ViewController1 class. Again not sure what your navigation code looks like so, add this there. For example

```
// Given ViewController 2
let vc2 = ViewController2()
vc2.delegate = self
```

I can give more detail in step 5 if I know how your transitioning:

1. Is your segue from a UI element in your storyboard?
2. Is your segue from ViewController1 to ViewController2 in your storyboard?